# Get first/last part of attribute via CSS attr()

Tags: html, css, dom, attributes

Is it possible to get only the first part of an attribute using `attr()` in CSS? By this I mean, targeting the part of an attribute before a certain character (a space, mainly). For example, from the attribute `hello="foo bar"` I would like to extract either `foo` or `bar`, just by using CSS.

Sincerely, I'd expect the answer to be 'no', but I'm not really sure.

Comment: By SASS you can do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic answer is no but in some particular case we can find some tricks. Since you have a space as a delimiter we can rely on [`word-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing) and/or [`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) and some overflow in order to hide a part of the word then adjust the `width`.

Here is an example:

```css
.first:before {
  content: attr(data-hello);
  word-spacing: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.first:after {
  content: attr(data-hello);
  text-indent: -60px;
  word-spacing:50px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="first" data-hello="foo bar">
  some text
</span>
```